# Any CSV Api in Java which can traverse back and forth in a CSV file > 1 Gb

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, csv

I have to write a code which will compare two CSVs (which is sorted). CSVs are auto-generated and always have more than 600,000 rows with more than 140 columns. It is not necessary that comparison will happen row by row. Few of the cells will be treated as Primary Key and will be matched against the rows in CSV2 and as soon as the match is found, that particular row in CSV2 will be compared. But for this, I will need to iterate CSV2 again and again for finding the matching rows in CSV2 (as it might happen that rows might be present in the beginning of CSV2 or in the very end). This will consume a lot of time.

Another approach I took was to split the files according to size. But, there was one more problem with this approach as some of the lines also split into two in the files. For example, if files were divided into two, Row 320 was not complete as only a part of it was present in the file1 and rest of it was present in the File2.

Using multi-threading (if each thread works on split files), there is one problem, as the header of the disk where the file is present will have to move as per each thread's requirements.

Also tried using JDBC (CSVDriver), but OutOfMemoryException was thrown owing to large CSV file.

Is there any approach, where we can go forth and back in a CSV using any File Reader or CSV Reader. For example, using CSV reader object, say doing this: csvReaderObject.get(120) gets me 120th row or csvReaderObject.contains() gets me the matching line numbers, something like that ?

Comment: Your question is very unclear without a concrete exampe of what you want to achieve, but the solution is probably to store the contents of your CSV files in a database and to use queries, unless you have enough RAM to store everything in memory.

Comment: If the input files are sorted according to the match criteria then you do not need to read one file multiple times, use a "merge" approach as documented many places. For example http://www.i-programmer.info/babbages-bag/755-the-magic-of-merging.html

Comment: I'd import the files into the database and compare them using SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the RandomAccessFile class which ensures data resides on disk and traverse both files in one loop in case you want to compare the lines one by one of each file or in case you want to compare each line in file 1 with all lines in file 2 you have to traverse them in two nested loops

The latter will have O(n^2) time complexity whereas the first will have O(n)

In case you want to use multi threading please ensure to create a RandomAccessFile instance per thread since there is only one cursor object.

Then just calculate batches based on the number of lines and assign each batch to another thread